# Using glob() to find directories with brackets in their names

Tags: php, glob, brackets

I have got directories which contain brackets in the names.
i.e. "dir_123[test@test.de]"

Within that dirs there are .tif files.

What I do is counting the Tif files. On my Mac I did that with MAMP and it worked great:

```
$anz = count(glob(str_replace("[", "\[", "dir_123[test@test.de]/*.tif")));
```

On my Windows machine running XAMPP it won't work because of that brackets:

```
$anz = count(glob(str_replace("[", "\[", "dir_123[test@test.de]\\*.tif")));
```

How can I get my XAMPP Server to read that directories?

Comment: Can you even have square brackets in filenames in windows?

Comment: @ Joe Freeman: yes you can.. 
@max: what is the errormsg, or result?

Comment: globe() returns an emty array, therefor $anz == 0

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to escape all the special characters?

Ex.

```
$dir = "dir_123[test@test.de]";

$from = array('[',']');
$to   = array('\[','\]');

$anz = count(glob(str_replace($from,$to,$dir . "\\*.tif")));
```

This works for me on Ubuntu.

If that ain't working you can do:

```
function countTif($dir) {
    $ret = 0;
    $scan = scandir($dir);
    foreach($scan as $cur) {
        $ret += ((substr($cur,-4) == ".tif")?1:0);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

And if you need recursive counting:

```
function countTif($dir) {
    $ret = 0;
    $scan = scandir($dir);
    foreach($scan as $cur) {
        if(is_dir("$dir/$cur") and !in_array($cur,array('.','..'))) {
            $ret += countTif("$dir/$cur");
        } else {
            $ret += ((substr($cur,-4) == ".tif")?1:0);
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

This functions was tested and worked on my Ubuntu 9.04 computer with php 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.1

Hope it works for ya!

//Linus Unnebäck

Comment: thx for your suggestions, Linus Unnebäck!
I am sure, they'd worked as well!

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?glob+7 for understanding wildcards for glob().

So, correct escaping is:

```
$pattern = "dir_123[test@test.de]/*.tif";
if ( strpos($pattern, '[') !== false || strpos($pattern, ']') !== false )
{
    $placeholder = uniqid();
    $replaces = array( $placeholder.'[', $placeholder.']', );
    $pattern = str_replace( array('[', ']', ), $replaces, $pattern);
    $pattern = str_replace( $replaces, array('[[]', '[]]', ), $pattern);
}
$anz = count(glob( $pattern ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using this code instead:

```
$dir = scandir("\\\\server\\dir");
foreach ($dir as $key=>$row)
    if (end(explode(".", $row)) != "tif")
        unset($dir[$key]);
$anz = count($dir);
```

Comment: your double quotes are unbalanced, my friend.

Comment: what do mean with unbalanced?